# Jquery-mobile not updating <input> value when widget "value" is changed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This is pretty strange: I create a simple range input using the JQM framework, and when it renders the nice-looking widget, the actual `<input>` element's value doesn't change when I move the range.

```
<input name="widget" id="widget" value="0" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" />
<!-- the value property doesn't change -->
```

You can see this for yourself in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/onr8Ln8L/1/) (use the DOM inspector). What's going on?

Comment: The `value` *DOM property* changes. The `value` *attribute* does not.

Comment: Oh goodness, I never realised that they didn't change together automagically. I'm self-taught, and I just took these things for granted! Thanks.